# Duplication of Data in mysql from Stringrequest Android Rest Api Php

Tags: php, android, rest

I am Sending Request from Android App Volley(String Request) When the data is insert in a Database it works Fine But some time it inserts a duplicate Values with new Order number I search Alot and Ad checks But its not working
its Happens some time i Thing when a wifi or network signals drops
Any one guide me how i can hanle it in php side

Here is my Php Api

```
        <?php
       // PHP code goes here
       include'config.php';

       $today = date("m");
       //$year=date("y");
       $day=date("d");
       $rand = strtoupper(substr(uniqid(sha1(time())),0,5));
        $unique = $today.$rand.$day;

       $reason_=$_POST["reason"];
       $s_number = $_POST["s_number"];
       $datetime_pri=$_POST["datetime_pri"];
       $bill=$_POST["bill"];
       $customer_address=$_POST["customer_address"];
       $customer_name=$_POST["customer_name"];
       $customer_phone=$_POST["customer_phone"];
       $date_time_order=$_POST["date_time_order"];
       $dilvery_charges=$_POST["dilvery_charges"];
       $phone_number=$_POST["phone_number"];
       $price=$_POST["price"];
       $shopname= $shopname= addslashes($_POST["shopname"]);
       $status=$_POST["status"];
       $total_bill=$_POST["total_bill"];
       $emailcus=$_POST["emailcus"];
       $id_customer=$_POST["id_cus"];

       if(isset($_POST["phone_number"]))
       {

           $sql_u = "SELECT * FROM Customer_order  WHERE             customer_phone = '$customer_phone' AND date_time_order = '$date_time_order' AND phone_number = '$phone'";

           $res_u = mysqli_query($con, $sql_u);
       if (mysqli_num_rows($res_u) > 0) {
          echo "Data already taken";
       }
       else
       {
           $sqlll="INSERT INTO `Customer_order`(`s_number`,            `datetime_pri`,
       `bill`, `customer_address`, `customer_name`, 
       `customer_phone`, `date_time_order`, `dilvery_charges`,
       `phone_number`, `price`, `shopname`, `status`, `total_bill`,            `reason`,`ordernumber`,`customer_email`,`customerId`) 
       VALUES            ('$s_number','$datetime_pri','$bill','$customer_address','$customer_name',
                  '$customer_phone','$date_time_order','$dilvery_charges','$phone_number',           '$price','$shopname','$status','$total_bill',
       '$reason_','$unique','$emailcus','$id_customer')";


       if ($con->query($sqlll) === TRUE) {
         echo "successfully" . "<br>";
       } else {
         echo "Error: " . $sqlll . "<br>" . $con->error;
       }
       }

        $content = $_POST['list_items'];
        //echo $content;
       $json = json_decode($content, true);
       foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
         // echo $value['Customer_phone'];
           // perform other actions.

          $itemprice=$value['price'];

        $quantity= $value['Item_quantity'];

        $price=$value['Items_price'];

       $totall= $value['Total_bill'];

       $dilivery= $value['dilvery_charges'];

       //$shopname= $value['shopname'];

        $shopname= addslashes($value['shopname']);

       $shopnumber=$value['phone_number'];

       $customerphone=$value['Customer_phone'];

       $latitude= $value['lattitude'];

       $lontitude= $value['longtitude'];
       $bill=$value['Total_bill'];
       $date= $value['date_time_order'];
       $itemname= addslashes( $value['Item_name']);
       $sub_detail=addslashes($value['description']);

        $sql_uu = "SELECT * FROM customer_Orders_Items  WHERE                        customer_phone= $customerphone AND date_time_order= $date  AND item_name = $itemname";
           $res_uu = mysqli_query($con, $sql_uu);
       if (mysqli_num_rows($res_uu) > 0) {
          echo "Data already taken";
       }
       else
       {

           $sql="INSERT INTO                       `customer_Orders_Items`(`customer_phone`,
         `date_time_order`, 
         `dilvery_charges`, 
         `item_name`, 
         `item_quantity`,
         `items_price`, 
         `lattitude`,
         `longtitude`,
         `phone_number`,
         `price`,
         `shopname`,
         `total_bill`,
         `sub_detail`,
         `orderNo`) VALUES (

         '$customerphone',
         '$date',
         '$dilivery',
         '$itemname',
         '$quantity',
         '$price',
         '$latitude',
         '$lontitude',
         '$shopnumber',
        '$itemprice',
        '$shopname',
         '$totall',
         '$sub_detail'
         ,'$unique')";
       if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
         //echo "items add successfully";
       } else {
         echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
       }


       }
       ;

       }


       }

       // $con->close();
       ?>
```

order number is change when duplicate data is insert because it created on API side

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks and it looks like you could have some SQL formatting issues that could lead to your select query not finding the records it could. Please check out mysqli_prepare(): https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

In android code you must use boolean variable for check double/multiple click

```
boolean send = false;
if(!send){
    send = true;
    //start volley
}
```

Comment: I added but i think Its network issue because android side only one request is send but in this side there is two request  parallels works same record insert  any guide line php side

Comment: add `Log.i("error", "send");` after `send = true;`. How many times `send` printed?

Comment: only one time print send

Comment: Both of customer_Orders_Items and Customer_order inserted twice?

Comment: Change `if ($con->query($sqlll) === TRUE) {` to and test again `if (TRUE === TRUE) {`